# Unable to read data using spark when alter table column name by changing type of it

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have hive table where I'm trying to `alter table tablename change col1 col1 <newdatatype>` using hive cli. I am able to alter it but while reading the table from spark, I'm getting cast exceptions.

```
scala> spark.sql("""alter table tablename change col1 col1 string""")

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
ALTER TABLE CHANGE COLUMN is not supported for changing column 'col1' with type 'LongType' to 'col1' with type 'StringType';
```

Comment: your error tells you what you are doing wrong.  you are trying to change type of your column from longType to StrngType.  which is not allowed.

Comment: Im able to do it in hive